# Angularjs and WebAPI - Authentication and Authorization

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to implement authentication and authorization in my application. I am developing my application using AngularJs and ASP.NET Web API.

I want to achieve:

1. Its an intranet application and want to use windows authentication.
2. For Authorization, we want to maintain a table in database with username and role column and using this table we will be authorizing users.

Please suggest how could I implement this within my application using AngularJs and Web API.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Usually Javascript front end's using a web API (i.e. REST) will use some kind of token authentication (look in to https://jwt.io/ and https://oauth.net/2/ )

Comment: If it's an intranet app with Windows Authentication you don't really need tokens since every request to the server will contain the user's ID in the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` property. That, combined with your table of roles, should be all you need to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your WebAPI libraries to use Windows Authentication. Add your `[Authorization]` attributes to your controllers. Your startup logic can certainly pull role names from your database and add those roles for use in the `[Authorization]` attributes on the controllers/methods.

I don't know that I'd do this on a per-username basis though - I'd create some roles (e.g. admin, user) and control those through AD if I was using Windows Auth.  I'd then just store the AD group names as my role names.

Angualr.JS doesn't really factor into the picture much at all here - the auth will be handled by the browser.  The one thing you may want or need is some way to get the user name from the `User` object in the API layer - in other words, creating an API method to return information about the logged in user (including that user's name, which won't be managed by the Angular.JS application as it might be if you were using some other form of authentication).